# How can I preserve the end of line (EOL) when using readline on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, readline, eol

I am modifying a bunch of files that are user-dependent. To do this, I am using the built-in "readline", but it swallows the EOL sequence that I wanted to preserve for the user.

Is there a way to achieve this with "readline", or should I opt for another  option?